# API call to Fathom Analytics via Postman

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an API call to Fathom Analytics. But I cannot figure out the filtering option (e.g. filter reportings for specific pathname). Can someone help me figuring this out?

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.usefathom.com/v1/aggregations?entity=pageview&entity_id=[SITE_ID_HERE]&aggregates=visits, uniques, pageviews, avg_duration, bounce_rate' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [BEARER_TOKEN_HERE]'
```

How can I insert the json-payload here in order to use the Fathom Filter option (https://usefathom.com/api#aggregation)

Also, I rebuilt the api call in python, without success. When I remove the payload from the API call it works just fine.

```
import requests

endpoint = "https://api.usefathom.com/v1/aggregations?entity=pageview&entity_id=[SITE_ID]&aggregates=pageviews,visits,uniques,avg_duration,bounce_rate&date_from=2022-10-01&date_to=2022-10-31"
payload = [{"property": "pathname",
        "operator": "is",
        "value": "/[URL TO FILTER]"}]
headers = {
    "Authorization": "[BEARER_TOKEN]"}

response=requests.get(endpoint, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a bit with this too, and in my case it worked when I included the "filter" key name in the JSON payload itself rather than the curl command.

Here's what worked for me:

```
curl https://api.usefathom.com/v1/aggregations \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer [BEARER_TOKEN_HERE]" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -d entity="pageview" \
  -d entity_id="[SITE_ID_HERE]" \
  -d aggregates="pageviews" \
  -d "{'filters': [{'property':'country', 'operator':'is', 'value':'UK'}]}" \
  -G
```

Moving the JSON to its own file (payload.json) and updating that curl line to this also worked:

```
  -d @payload.json \
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with the filters. I wish I could use a POST request.

Here's the Laravel code that worked for me:

```php
Http::withToken(config('services.fathom.client_secret'))
    ->acceptJson()
    ->get('https://api.usefathom.com/v1/aggregations', [
        'entity' => 'pageview',
        'entity_id' => config('services.fathom.site_id'),
        'aggregates' => 'visits',
        'date_grouping' => 'day',
        'date_from' => (string) today()->subDays(7),
        'filters' => json_encode([
            [
                'property' => 'hostname',
                'operator' => 'is',
                'value' => 'https://example.com',
            ],
        ]),
    ])
    ->throw()
    ->json();
```